# How do I remove \r without removing \n?

Tags: regex, perl, newline, carriage-return

so I will try to make it as simple as possible. I am formatting files right now. These are the tasks that the script should complete:

1. delete `\r\n`
2. delete `&`
3. replace `#A` with `\n#A`
4. replace `#D` with `\n#D`

My code is already working but it also adds `\r` in front on every `\n` added, and that's something I don't want because `\r` isn't recognized by the program I want to import my files to. Do you know a method to only delete `\r` without removing also the `\n`?

Here's my code. I guess only the last `$data =~ s!\r!!g;` is relevant. Why isn't this working like intented? There is still `\r\n` after every row...

```
opendir my $dir_a, $scriptdir or die "Kann Verzeichnis nicht oeffnen: $!";
my @stammdateien = grep { /root/ } readdir $dir_a;
closedir $dir_a;

foreach my $stammdatei (@stammdateien){
if ($stammdatei eq "root101" or $stammdatei eq "root112" or    $stammdatei eq "root116"){
    my $stammdateipfad = "$scriptdir\\$stammdatei";
    my $data = lese_file($stammdateipfad);
    $data =~ s!\r|\n!!g;
    $data =~ s!&!!g;
    $data =~ s!#A!\n#A!g;
    $data =~ s!#D!\n#D!g;
    $data =~ s!#M \| INSERT \|!#M \| UPDATE_INSERT \|!g;
    $data =~ s!\r!!g;
    schreibe_file($stammdateipfad, $data);  
}
}

sub lese_file {
my ($stammdatei) = @_;
open my $in, "<", $stammdatei or die "Konnte die Datei '$stammdatei' nicht zum lesen oeffnen: $!";
local $/ = undef;
my $all = <$in>;
close $in;
return $all;
}


sub schreibe_file {
my ($stammdateipfadout, $data) = @_;
my $outputdatei = "$stammdateipfadout"."_CONVERTED";
open my $out, ">", "$outputdatei" or die "Konnte die Datei $outputdatei nicht zum schreiben oeffnen: $!";
print $out $data;
close $out;
print "====> Vorgang abgeschlossen!\n\n";
return;
}
```

Comment: `$data =~ s![\r\n]+!\n!g;` or `$data =~ s![\r\n]+$!\n!g;`

Comment: @ssr1012 sadly not working, when loading up with "show all characters" in notepad++ it still shows CR LF at the end of every line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you on a Windows platform? The default IO layer translates `\n` to `\r\n` on Windows. To disable that, try one of:

```
open my $out, ">", "$outputdatei" or ...;
binmode $out;

open my $out, ">:raw", "$outputdatei" or
```

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing.

Comment: yep, this is working well, thanks! :) edit: used the `binmode $out;` variant!