# How to Remove \r without Removing \n in Python

Tags: python, doctest

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022811/how-do-i-remove-r-without-removing-n) but it is in Perl which I couldn't understand the solution

I must pass this doctest:

```
**********************************************************************
File "c:\Users\sb\Desktop\test_wc\doctest_wc.py", line 4, in __main__
Failed example:
    subprocess.check_output('python3 wc.py ./testinputs/text1.txt ', shell=True)
Expected:
    b'\t10\t10\t20\t./testinputs/text1.txt\n'
Got:
    b'\t10\t10\t20\t./testinputs/text1.txt\r\n'
**********************************************************************
File "c:\Users\sb\Desktop\test_wc\doctest_wc.py", line 8, in __main__
Failed example:
    subprocess.check_output('python3 wc.py ./testinputs/text.txt', shell=True)
Expected:
    b'wc.py: ./testinputs/text.txt: No such file or directory\n'
Got:
    b'wc.py: ./testinputs/text.txt: No such file or directory\r\n'
**********************************************************************
File "c:\Users\sb\Desktop\test_wc\doctest_wc.py", line 12, in __main__
Failed example:
    subprocess.check_output('python3 wc.py ./testinputs/empty.txt', shell=True)
Expected:
    b'\t0\t0\t0\t./testinputs/empty.txt\n'
Got:
    b'\t0\t0\t0\t./testinputs/empty.txt\r\n'
**********************************************************************
File "c:\Users\sb\Desktop\test_wc\doctest_wc.py", line 16, in __main__
Failed example:
    subprocess.check_output('python3 wc.py ./testinputs/text2.txt', shell=True)
Expected:
    b'\t2\t8\t52\t./testinputs/text2.txt\n'
Got:
    b'\t2\t8\t52\t./testinputs/text2.txt\r\n'
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   4 of   5 in __main__
***Test Failed*** 4 failures.
```

here is my filed attempt:

```
sys.stdout.write(main().strip("\r") + str("\n")) # main() returns a string
```

when I remove `\r`, `\n` disappears with it, when I re-insert `\n`, `\r` comes back with it

Comment: This almost sounds like a line endings issue with the particular (Windows) editor you are using, rather than a problem with your Python script.

Comment: You most likely want [``universal_newlines``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) in order to have consistent line endings across different OS'.

Comment: Can you include your code or an MRE?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on actual post, hence I am posting as an answer. You might need to change the newline character instead of replacing.

Comment: @spen.smith my code: https://onecompiler.com/python/3wrrybvas,

Comment: @spen.smith sorry that is the test, this is the code https://onecompiler.com/python/3wrryp9zh

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You mean that when my teacher run the test on his Mac the \r will disappear ?, i know he uses Mac

Comment: @manhoty Yes. Unix (MacOS and Linux) use ``\n`` line endings whereas Windows uses ``\r\n``. The tests seem to be written only with Unix line endings in mind. Python will normalise them when using ``universal_newlines``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ah we need a standardization here i spent hours on this

Comment: Thank you all dears